# CSS / Bootstrap: Want to locate 2 div side by side in a div

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

My question above below is my current code:

```
        <!-- Masthead-->
    <header class="masthead">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="masthead-subheading" style="color: black;">Welcome</div>
            <div class="masthead-heading" style="color: black;">Dr. Lim Wee Chai</div>
            <div class="ml12" style="color: black;">My Life, My Journey</div>
            <div style="float:left;"><img src = "about.png" width="50%" height="32%"/></div>
        </div>

    </header>
```

and below is the result

[image]

Can anyone help to on how to make sure that the image is at the left side (beside word Dr. Lim Wee Chai)?

Answer (score 0):

You should use rows and columns
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Answer (score 0):

You are not using bootstrap `grid` utility. Read the [Grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) doc to learn more.

You can set a two-column grid that set div side-by-side using `col` class assign to the div. However, the grid has a defined structure that you will have to follow. See below.

Any column must have a row. In another word, the column/s should be the child/s of the row.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col"></div>
    ...
</div>
```

You can set a min one and max twelve columns per row. Read bootstrap [grid doc](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) to learn more.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/12/30/14/13/snail-4729777_960_720.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <h2>Equal-width</h2>
      <p>For example, here are two grid layouts that apply to every device and viewport, from xs to xl. Add any number of unit-less classes for each breakpoint you need and every column will be the same width.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for < nobr> !